# Javadoc not configured correctly

Tags: eclipse, macos, javadoc

Im getting a message like in the picture that my Javadoc is not set up correctly. I have already tried downloading and added the URL and jar file to java JRE in preferences under installed JRE's.

I dont know if it matters but my dependency is coming from artifactory. 
Im also running eclipse 4.9
Im trying to add 
https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.6/index.html
https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/

[image]

Comment: The JRE preferences won't affect the location of docs for libraries that are not part of a JRE.

Comment: Yes, if you were using Maven Central, the sources would be downloaded automatically and you shouldn't have the problem. Solves the manual download of the `*-sources.jar` files from the following source into the Maven repository directory that is mentioned in the error dialog the problem? http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.6.6/

Comment: @howlger Im not sure what you are asking.

Comment: Is your project a Maven project using a pom.xml file? Do you have the m2e plug-ins installed to support Maven in Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the issue.

To solve it:

Right click java project -> `Properties`.

In properties select `Java Build Path` -> select the `Library` tab.

Here I untwisted `Maven Dependencies`, and untwisted `.jar` file.

Select `Javadoc location` and click `edit` on the right side to add the documentation URL.